# How is this application different from Greenlite's 1995 PCT/EP1995/001527 (WO1995029094 A1)

Tags: ep2548802a2

Except from the fact that the claims are narrower in the Airbus patent, there doesn't seem to be any new element over the original "aircraft with driven wheel(s)" patent from 1995. This patent itself cites relevant patents from 1961 and 1962, so some prior art is now in the public domain. The Airbus patent is very broad regarding the power transmission medium, which can be anything but a direct shaft.

Operation from either the APU or the main engines was disclosed, both being air breathing turbine engines. Power transmission via hydraulics and electrical systems was disclosed, and the remaining possibilities don't seem very practical.

The last claims may give a hint, but a jet engine on which thrust and accessory power extraction can be independently set is not new either.

[wo1995029094 Greenlite](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/WO1995029094)